# Setting enumeration-indexed vector in derived model

Tags: modelica

I define

```
type Enum = enumeration(A, B, C);
```

and

```
partial model PM
  parameter Real[Enum] a;
...
end PM;
```

and

```
model M
  extends PM(a = {1, 2, 3});
...
end M;
```

which gives an error. My best guess is that the `a = {1, 2, 3}` is the culprit. Is this indeed illegal, and if so, how can I set `a` in `M`?

---

UPDATE

Upon further examination I've found that everything above is indeed legal. Let me just go the whole hog:

```
type Enum = enumeration(A, B, C);

connector Conn
  Real[Enum] a;
  flow Real[Enum] f;
end Conn;

model M1
  Conn conn;
equation
  conn.f = -conn.a;
end M1;

model M2
  Conn conn;
initial equation
  conn.a = {1, 2, 3};
equation
  der(conn.a) = conn.f;
end M2;

model M3
  M1 m1;
  M2 m2;
equation
  connect(m1.conn, m2.conn);
end M3;
```

This fails to build. But if I just change each `Enum` in the connector class to `3`, then it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example is (as far as I can tell) legal, and some tools already handle it (assuming there is nothing else hidden).

Since you need a tool-specific work-around you need to specify which tool.

The legality will be clarified further in later versions of the Modelica specification since it was unclear - https://trac.modelica.org/Modelica/ticket/2212#comment:3

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'm using Wolfram|One, which presumably behaves the same as SystemModeler. I've just added an update too.